# Postgres foreign check constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to apply a PostgreSQL check constraint to a foreign column?
It is possible to get the same effect without a foreign check constraint like this:

```
create table a (
  id serial primary key,
  flag boolean,
  unique(id, flag)
);

create table b (
  id serial primary key,
  a_id integer,
  yup_true boolean not null default true,
  foreign key (a_id, yup_true) references a(id, flag)
);
```

but that's a bit awkward. Is there a way to apply that check directly to the foreign column?

EDIT:
The desire is, in this case, to only allow `b` to reference rows in `a` where the `flag` column is `true`, using check constraints. The example shows a way it could be done using foreign key constraints, but the question is specifically if/how it could be done using check constraints.
An example of what that might look like (which is totally wrong, and needs to be made to work) is below:

```
create table a (
  id serial primary key,
  flag boolean
);

create table b (
  id serial primary key,
  a_id integer references a(id),
  check(a(flag))
);
```

EDIT2:
example of data in tables and what rows would be valid and invalid

```
table a
| id | flag |
| -- | ---- |
|  1 | true |
|  2 | false|
| -- | ---- |

table b
| id | a_id | yup_true |
| -- | ---- | -------- |
|  1 |    1 |     true | VALID
|  2 |    2 |     true | NOT VALID ( no a with id 2, flag false)
|  3 |    7 |     true | NOT VALID ( no a with id 7)
| -- | ---- | -------- |
```

Comment: `references a(id, flag)` will **not** work as `flag` is not part of the primary key of table `a`. But if you require the `yup_true` column to always have the same value as the `flag` column in table `a`, then just don't store that value in table `b`

Comment: please update the question with structure you have and a clear goal - instead of "somewhat like" not working solution of unclear task

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "to a foreign column"? Do you mean a reference to a foreign table? Or do you mean the column of a foreign key constraint? Or the check constraint to a column in a foreign table?

Comment: Can you try to add some *explanation* of what you're trying to do? Maybe some sample data for `a` and then some potential rows for `b` and which ones should be allowed/which ones not?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just added an summary to the rollback. I do mean applying a check constraint directly to a column on a foreign table, not to a foreign key column.

Comment: So where is the foreign table in your example? You need to add the `create foreign table` statement in order to make this clear

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah, I see that's confusing. I don't mean a foreign table like the pg foreign data feature. I just mean the row in table `a`, referenced by `a_id`. But I want to apply the constraint directly to `flag`, not to `a.id`

Comment: Standard SQL describes a feature called `ASSERTION` that is like a `CHECK` constraint but not limited to a single table/row. Unfortunately, no real products tend to implement it.

Comment: Can you show us examples of data in table a and b, then show us what data in table b should be valid for check and what is invalid? I read it all and still can't quite get it.

Comment: What should happen if `a.flag` is false :: should no `b.a_id` row be allowed to refer to it ?

Comment: @joop yes, it should fail like any other check